Approximating the poisson distribution using normal distribution
The number of calls $X$ to a telephone exchange during the busiest hour of the day follows a Poisson distribution $Po(λ)$. Over $8$ days, the following independent observations of $X$ have been recorded: $115, 82, 108, 106, 118, 87, 99, 92$. Determine an approximate $95$% confidence interval for $λ$.


If I understand correctly x is a random variable for each day and Y is a random variable of the sum of the X's and thus E(Y) is the mean of the random variables which is 8 times the average. So the average of Y will then be the same as the average of X since we divide it by 8 (I am unsure here). The variance of Y is then also divided by the sample size and thus the standarad deviation as well.
Is this a correct understanding of the solution? My question is then why did we have to think about another random variable Y? Why are we taking its mean and variance. This is really not clear for me.

I think the point of the question is to appeal to the central limit theorem (CLT), which states that for i.i.d. observations $X_{i}$ with $E[X_{i}^{2}] < \infty$ (so that the variance exists), we have as $n\to\infty$
$$
\sqrt{n}(\bar{X}_{n} - E[X_{1}]) \overset{d}{\to} N(0, var(X_{1})),
$$
which justifies the approximation in finite samples of
$$
\bar{X}_{n} \approx N(E[X_{1}], \frac{1}{n}var(X_{1})).
$$
For the Poisson distribution, we have $E[X_{1}] = var(X_{1}) = \lambda$, but since this is unknown, we replace it by an estimate (in this case $\bar{X}_{n}$), so our approximation becomes (with some abuse of notation)
$$
\bar{X}_{n} \approx N(\lambda, \frac{1}{n}\lambda),
$$
which justifies the confidence interval
$$
\lambda \in \bar{x} \pm z_{\alpha/2}\sqrt{\frac{\bar{x}}{n}},
$$
where $z_{\alpha/2}$ is the number such that for a standard normal random variable it holds that $P(Z\leq z_{\alpha/2}) = 1-\alpha/2$.
The above can also be restated for sums of i.i.d. random variables, you can multiply each approximation with $n$ to get e.g.
$$
Y = \sum_{i=1}^{n}X_{i} \approx N(nE[X_{1}], var(X_{1})).
$$

(+1) It may be worth mentioning that, assuming the $X_i$ are i.i.d. and $E(X_i)\lt\infty,$ we have that $\bar X_n$ is a strongly consistent estimator for its expected value $\lambda,$ i.e. $P[\bar X_n\to \lambda]=1,$ which helps to justify using $\bar X_n$ as a substitute for $\lambda$ in the CLT.
